# UnitSimplify returns unexpected non-SI unit combination

Tags: units

I am trying to get units working in mathematica in the following expression for diffusion:

$D = {K_B  T}/{3 \pi \eta L}$

My code is as follows:

```
KB = Quantity[1.380650*10^-23, ("Meters")^2*"Kilograms"*("Seconds")^-2*("Kelvins")^-1];
T = Quantity[20 + 273.15, "Kelvins"];
eta0 = Quantity[8.9*10^-4, "Pascals"*"Seconds"];
L = Quantity[200*10^-9, "Meters"];

D = (KB*T)/(3*Pi*eta0*L)
```

This evaluates to:

$2.41258\times10^{-12}\,\text{kg}\, \text{m}\text{/(}\text{s}^3\text{Pa})$

Which under `UnitSimplify` reduces to:

$2.41258\times10^{-12}\,\text{V}/\text{T}\,\, ... \,\,(volts\,per\,tesla??)$

for diffusion coefficients I am expecting units of $meters^{2}/second$.

Can anyone see whats gone wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UnitSimplify` simplifies the units it doesn't guarantee it'll give you the units in SI. Just use `UnitConvert`, it gives you the answer in SI units.

```
UnitConvert[(KB T)/(3 Pi eta0 L)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh thanks. So what exactly is happening when it gives me V/T?

Comment: @SteveHatcher Well, 1 Volt is equivalent to 1 kg m^2/(s^3 A) and 1 Tesla is equivalent to 1 kg/(s^2 A) so it is actually correct that 1 m^2/s is equal to 1 V/T

Comment: oh great. thanks